# Log statements from within triggers in Postgresql

Tags: postgresql

I have several sql statements running in some of my `plpgsql` triggers. I've enabled logging with the `log_statement = 'all'`. It logs the 'triggering statement', but not the statements within the query itself.

Is there a way to display statements that were executed within trigger in standard postgres log?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [`auto_explain` module](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/auto-explain.html) has `auto_explain.log_nested_statements` since at least 8.4, so that's one option. It's a bit heavyweight but I'm not aware of any other logging option that will record statements run inside PL/PgSQL functions and triggers.

See [this similar question](https://serverfault.com/q/20106/102814).